# Problem with replace-regexp - Invalid use of \ in replacement

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to add extra expressions to some JS code, but taking care of the correct element ID (in the example below, the ID is `scatter`).

```
document.getElementById("scatter").height="400"; -->
document.getElementById("scatter").height="400"; document.getElementById("scatter").style="visibility: visible";
```

My attempt so far has been:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET 
Id("\(\w+\)").height="400"; RET 
Id("\0").height="400"; document.getElementById("\0").style="visibility: visible";
```

Where `\(\w+\)` grabs the element ID and `\0` references it on the replacement string.
Unfortunately `replace-regexp` is complaining that I'm using `\`incorrectly.

Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\1` instead of `\0`.

Comment: That solved it, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regexp replacement pattern, `\N` matches a subgroup, and `\1`, not `\0` matches the first subgroup.

I just filed Emacs bug #[23884](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23884) to help clarify the doc about this.